# Shapley values, different versions of the symmetry axiom

Tags: discrete-mathematics, permutations, game-theory

I have come across different versions of the axioms, from which the Shapley values (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shapley_value) are derived. I want to prove that these are equivalent, but I miss an argument for the symmetry axiom.

The first version of the axioms is from the Shapley paper (1953) (http://library.fa.ru/files/Roth2.pdf page 33):

**Axiom 1 (symmetry):** For each $\pi \in \Pi (U)$, $\phi_{\pi i} [\pi v] = \phi_i[v]$

**Axiom 2 (efficiency):** For each carrier N of $v$, $\Sigma_{i \in N} \phi_i[v] = v(N)$

**Axiom 3 (law of aggregation):** For any two games $v$ and $w$, $\phi[v + w] = \phi[v] + \phi[w]$

- Here v is the game, i.e. a function from the subsets of U to the real numbers,
- $U$ is the set of players
- $\Pi(U)$ is the set of permutations on $U$,
- $\pi v$ is defined by $\pi v(\pi S) = v(S)$ for all $S \subseteq U$,
- $\phi_i$ is the attribution to player i,
- and a carrier $N$ is a subset of $U$ such that $v(N \cap S) = v(S)$ for all $S \subseteq U$.

Another version uses a modified set of axioms. Let's refer to these as properties to distinguish them:

**Property 1 (symmetry):** If $v(S \cup i) = v(S \cup j)$ for all $S \subseteq U\backslash \{i,j\}$, then $\phi_i[v]=\phi_j[v]$

**Property 2 (efficiency):** $\Sigma_{i \in U} \phi_i[v] = v(U)$

**Property 3 (dummy):** If $v(S \cup j) = v(S)$ for all $S \subseteq \ {j}$, then $\phi_i[v] = 0$

**Property 4 (law of aggregation):** For any two games $v$ and $w$, $\phi[v + w] = \phi[v] + \phi[w]$

I have shown that the three axioms are equivalent to the four properties, except I need to show that **Axiom 1 (symmetry)** is implied by the properties (I guess, just by property 1).

Can someone see how this follows?

Comment: Give us a bit of the context (game theory ?)...

Comment: Yes, it is from game theory. The setup is, that we have an n-person (n players) game v, where we need to attribute each player a value according to the his contribution to the game (say they have to share the money prize they win by playing the game). Shapley showed (in the paper I linked to) that if you want the three axioms to hold for the attribution procedure, there is one unique solution (Shapley values). My problem is just to show that the symmetry property implies the symmetry axiom, which by itself is not a specific game theoretical problem. Was this the context, you were looking for?

Comment: Yes, thank you for your detailed answer that will help. Unfortunately I am not familiar with the domain. Besides, if it can help others, I just found a very pedagogical chapter on Shapley values (https://christophm.github.io/interpretable-ml-book/shapley.html) part of an interesting recent book by Christoph Molnar "Interpretable Machine Learning" accessible on-line as you can see.

Answer (score 1):

I stumbled on your question while looking for its answer.

One can go about it by repeating Shapley's proof with `P1-P4` instead of the original axioms, i.e. proving that all value functions which satisfy `P1-P4` coincide with Shapley's values for games with finite carriers.

Since Shapley's values satisfy Axiom 1, it follows that `P1-P4` imply the original axioms *for games $v$ with finite carriers*.

Personally I don't find this satisfactory - maybe there is a proof that doesn't require going through all the steps of Shapley's proof - but I couldn't find it. I provide the details of how the proof is modified below.

---

Lemma 1 follows from the 'dummy' property. For any $i \notin N$, where $N$ is a carrier:

$$
v(S \cup \left\{i\right\}) = v\left((S \cup \left\{i\right\}) \cap N\right) = v(S \cap N) = v(S)
$$

Lemma 2 holds unchanged since it does not involve the notion of value function.

For Lemma 3 ($\phi_i[c\, v_R ] = \frac{c}{|R|} \mathbb{1}(i \in R)$):

- for $i \notin R$, $\phi_i[c\, v_R ] = 0\;$ follows directly from the 'dummy' property
- if $i,\,j \in R$, the 'symmetry' property implies that $\phi_i[c\, v_R ] = \phi_j[c\, v_R ]$, so all elements of $R$ have equal values and they should sum up to $c$ according to the 'efficiency property'

The rest of the proof makes use of the 'law of aggregation' which is in common between Axioms and Properties.